# Flutter ElevatedButton color not updating based on state

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, colors, state-management

I'm currently working on a Flutter application, and I'm facing an issue with the color of an ElevatedButton not updating as expected based on the state changes. I have a button with a circular shape that is supposed to change its color between green and red based on the isListeningMic state.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
ClipOval(
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Check if speech is not currently listening
      if (!speech.isListening) {
        // Start listening and update UI
        startListening(productNameController, productNameFocusNode);
        setState(() {
          isListeningMic = true; // Set isListeningMic to true
          print("isListeningMic set to true");
        });
      } else {
        // Stop listening and update UI
        stopListening();
        setState(() {
          isListeningMic = false; // Set isListeningMic to false
          print("isListeningMic set to false");
        });
      }
    },
    style: ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
        (states) => CircleBorder(), // Set button shape to a circle
      ),
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
          // Change the button color based on the isListeningMic state
          return isListeningMic ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
        },
      ),
    ),
    child: Icon(Icons.mic), // Display a microphone icon on the button
  ),
)
```

Despite the state changes, the button color doesn't update accordingly. I've confirmed that the isListeningMic state is changing as expected, but the button color remains unchanged.

I've already tried MaterialStateProperty approch, but none seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Try it in DartPad: [link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=654a540f82d834ecb64cfcd921e3de54) (I modified the `onPressed` callback because I don't know about that `speech` variable)